# CSS table cell expand to maximum available length

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I need a "simple" layout for my tables where the first and second columns should not wrap while the third one should expand as much as possible and wrap if the width of the display has been reached.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Temp</td>
      <td>&nbsp;=&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Result</td>
      <td>&nbsp;=&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam auctor ligula non tincidunt ornare. </td>
    </tr>                   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For short cells in the third column the display should be as follows

```
Temp   = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Result = Aliquam auctor ligula non tincidunt ornare.
```

while for longer cells in the third column the display should be

```
Temp   = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
         Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes. 
Result = Aliquam auctor ligula non tincidunt ornare. Fusce dapibus 
         tortor et odio fermentum, in dictum odio finibus. Sed 
         egestas ex mi, eu fermentum eros vestibulum nec.
```

Such tables are for an ebook in epub format. I have tried many possible combinations of various CSS attributes (width, display, table-layout, ...) and their values but haven't arrived to produce the desired result.

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/1cwaoosz/ (You can resize the splitter to see the width)

Comment: Yes, but in many ebook readers (e.g. Adobe Digital Editions) the third column is wrapped even if it fits as a single line in the display. When adding width:auto for the td in third colum then the first column display 1 letter each line (R<cr>e<cr>s<cr>u<cr>l<cr>t<cr>) :-(

Comment: can't help you if i can't reproduce it

Comment: maybe use a css only for that reader with a fixed width